# WSO2 CEP Can't access dashboard

Tags: console, wso2, dashboard, complex-event-processing

I've installed wso2 cep tool in a private cloud, hence I've a public ip address that is NATted to an internal ip address.
When I try to access to cep dashboard from the web console this one hangs because the web application redirects the browser to the internal ip address instead of the public one.
I've still set in file /etc/hosts the internal ip address to the host name as suggested in another post (even if it seemed wierd to me) but no luck.
Any clue?
Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Please set the necessary public IP in SSO-idp-config.xml (in /repository/conf/) file.. Follow [1]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP310/Running+the+Dashboard

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work... same behaviour, tries to connect to the internal ip address.   Any other idea?

Comment: I have tried that and it is working fine. below is the entry I have changed..                                                                                                                           <ServiceProvider>
            <Issuer>cep-dash</Issuer>
            <AssertionConsumerService>https://101.2.186.122:9443/cep-dash/acs</AssertionConsumerService>
            <SignResponse>true</SignResponse>
            <CustomLoginPage>/cep-dash/login.jag</CustomLoginPage>
        </ServiceProvider>